# Which AWS EC2 region is the best for hosting a global site?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, latency

I'm looking for a suggestion to choose a region for a global site(Not targetted for any specific country/region). At the moment I'm looking for a simpler solution without having multiple replicas in different regions. So I'm wondering if anybody knows which AWS region is best in terms of latency all across the world? I'm also open to suggestions for tools like [cloudping.info](https://www.cloudping.info/).

Thank you

Comment: If global latency is a concern, the region choice isn't the right question. CDNs, data replication, edge compute, etc. are more important.

Answer (score 1):

Pick any of the US Locations. They're the most actively regulated and monitored when compared with other locations.

Answer (score 1):

Pick one, all such data centers are highly connected. Choose a region with low network latency to the majority of your users. Usually there is a country with more users or better Internet, even for a global presence.

The best measure of latency is instrumenting your applications to measure end user experience. Packet level (TCP/UDP/QUIC) latency is a decent substitute if your visibility is limited to layer 4.

Caching data closer to users can be done without replicating everything. Consider CDN as a service. Or try locating additional application servers and a caching tier in a distant region, far from the primary database.

If your organization cares about data sovereignty or other political issues, include those in your decision.